# How to return a string as an int macro call?

Tags: c

If I have

```
#define hello 0
```

and a function such as

```
int func()
{
  return "hello";
}
```

How do I make it so that it returns 0 from a string instead of calling

`return 0;`

or

`return hello;`

Directly?
I tried converting that string into an int but that did not work.

Comment: The macro name doesn't exist at runtime. It's replaced by the preprocessor before the code is compiled. You can't do this. I can't think of a reasonable use case for this though either. What's your actual end goal? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I want to check if an input string is equal to one of the macro. I want a shortcut instead of writing switches

Comment: Where does the string `"hello"` come from? Is it actually a variable whose value you need to compare with the macro name?

Comment: In the function, `return "hello";` won't get any pre-processor treatment because it is a string literal.

Comment: Make an array of strings initialized with all the macros, and loop over the array calling `strcmp()`.

Comment: @Barmar ohhh. And match the index of the string array with the macro. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can match the string to an index, or you can create an array of `struct` where each `struct` has a string and a value. That way the value assigned to each string can be whatever you want.